# Hierarchical tree with multiple sub items

Tags: wpf, mvvm, tree, hierarchicaldatatemplate

I am trying to wrap my head around how to solve this problem in WPF using an MVVM pattern.

I am converting a win32 tree control into WPF.  The old tree control uses a Node class hierarchy along these lines (BaseNode being the base class and each following item inheriting from it and extending slightly):
BaseNode, GroupNode, VehicleNode, PersonNode, EquipmentNode, SupplyNodes (etc, etc.)

Going from this, A GroupNode will have a list of child nodes which could be one or more GroupNodes, one or more VehicleNodes and one or more PersonNodes.

A VehicleNode would have a list of PersonNodes that would be the crew for operating the vehicle.  The VehicleNode would also have a list of PersonNodes that would be passengers in the vehicle.  Each of these is under a 'Dummy' node labeled Crew and Passengers (though they are both PersonNode Types).

Outside of this, a VehicleNode and PersonNode would each have EquipmentNodes and SupplyNodes.

The tree will have several "Group" nodes that will be expanded to list any items of that type.

Hopefully, this text diagram will help solve illustrate the problem.

- Ground Fleet (GroupNode)

  - West Coast (GroupNode)
  - East Coast (GroupNode)

    - Truck 1 (VehicleNode)
    - Truck 2 (VehicleNode)

      - Crew (DummyNode)

        - Bill the Driver (PersonNode)
      - Passengers (DummyNode)

        - Passenger 1 (PersonNode)
        - Passenger 2 (PersonNode)

          - Equipment (DummyNode)

            - Camera  (EquipmentNode)
            - Sunglasses (EquipmentNode)
          - Supplies (DummyNode)

            - Apple (SupplyNode)
            - Water Bottle (SupplyNode)
        - Equipment (DummyNode)

          - Jack (EquipmentNode)
          - Tire Iron (EquipmentNode)
        - Supplies (DummyNode)

          - SpareTire (SupplyNode)
    - Personnel (DummyNode)

      - Salesman Tom (PersonNode)
      - District Manager Sally (PersonNode)

So the instance of Truck 2 (VehicleNode) has six child nodes (list of BaseNodes) of various types:
List children; // {Bill The Driver(PersonNode), Passenger 1 (PersonNode), Passenger 2 (PersonNode), Jack (EquipmentNode), Tire Iron (EquipmentNode), SpareTire (SupplyNode)}

In our existing win32 tree, when we add the Truck 2 node, we manually cycle through the child nodes and add the dummy nodes (As required) and children to create the tree based on the type of nodes in the children list and potentially a property on the child node - the PersonNode has a flag on it to indicate if its a passenger or crew, so we know which parent node to add it should belong to.

I'm struggling with how this can be represented in an MVVM approach on a tree that would allow us to retain the Dummy Nodes as above.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I for one do not understand the problem...

Answer (score 0):

Use [HierarchicalDataTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.hierarchicaldatatemplate.aspx), see a decent example [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2009/10/30/treeview-and-hierarchicaldatatemplate-step-by-step.aspx).

You would expose a list of nodes from your ViewModel, and bind that to an ItemsSource of a TreeView.  Each node will also have a child property that is another list of nodes.

Each of you nodes could just be a simple class, or could actually be ViewModels themselves if you need to put ICommands/Actions/Methods at each node.

Each node can be setup however you wish in C# in your ViewModel, since HierarchicalDataTemplate does alot of binding work for you.

Comment: It seems that this would work - I wasn't aware that the hierarchical data template could have sub-templates.  Thanks!

Comment: You should mark as answer/upvote if this solved your problem.